# Angular help! Can't use API response data. Problem with interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular newb working on class project. I'm close to finished, but then hit a wall.

The application is supposed to:

1. Load SVG image of world map and sidebar where country data will display  // works okay!
2. Add click event listeners to SVG paths  // works okay!
3. When SVG path is clicked, listener grabs country code from SVG and fires API call to geonames API. // works okay!
4. API response contains country info/stats, which should update text fields on screen.  // not working...

Everyting works up until I try to use the API data to display the country stats. The response data doesn't seem accessible uisng my interface.

For what its worth, I followed along a Pluralsight course to get me to this point, but the course might be a little outdated.

**app-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WorldService } from "./world/world.service";
import { IWorld } from "./world/country";
import { map } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'wgu-map';
  countries: Array<IWorld> = [];

  constructor(public worldService: WorldService) {}

  addListeners() {
    const paths = document.querySelectorAll("path, g");
    for(let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
      if(paths[i].id){
        paths[i].addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => this.worldService.getCountryInfo(paths[i].id)
          .subscribe((response: IWorld[]) => {
            console.log("API response: ", response);
            this.countries = response;
          })
        )
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.addListeners();
  };
}
```

**app-component.html (template)**

```
<div>
        <h1 id="title">Country Info</h1>
        <div class="country-info" style="margin-left: 10px">

           // This is where I get the error
           // Trying to access the API data from the local variable where I saved it. 
           // {{countries.countryName}} throws error - Property 'countryName' does not exist on type 'IWorld[]'.


          <p>Country Name: <span>{{ countries.countryName }}</span></p>
          <p>Country Capital: <span></span></p>
          <p>Country Region: <span></span></p>
          <p>Income Level: <span></span></p>
          <p>Population: <span></span></p>
          <p>Continent: <span></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**world-service.ts (handles API call)**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {catchError, map, Observable, tap, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {IWorld} from "./country";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WorldService{
  public url = "";
  public suffix = "";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCountryInfo( info:string ): Observable<IWorld[]> {
    this.url = `http://api.geonames.org/countryInfo?country=${this.getCountryCode(info)}&username=brentmercer&type=json`;
    console.log("API call to: " + this.url);
    return this.callApi(this.url);
  }

  getCountryCode(countryCode:string){
    return this.suffix = countryCode;
  };

  callApi(url:string){
    return this.http.get<IWorld[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log("All: ", JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError),
        map(responseData => {
          console.log("Response data: ", responseData);
          const detailArray = [];
          for (const key in responseData) {
            if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) detailArray.push(responseData[key]);
          }
          console.log("Detailed arrays: ", detailArray);
          return detailArray;
        })
      )
  }
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(err.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is ${err.message}`
    }
    console.log(errorMessage)
    return throwError(() => errorMessage);
  }
}
```

**country.ts (interface)**

```
export interface IWorld{
  "continent": string;
  "capital": string;
  "languages": string;
  "geonameId": string;
  "south": string;
  "isoAlpha3": string;
  "north": string;
  "fipsCode": string;
  "population": string;
  "east": string;
  "isoNumeric": string;
  "areaInSqKm": string;
  "countryCode": string;
  "west": string;
  "countryName": string;
  "postalCodeFormat": string;
  "continentName": string;
  "currencyCode": string;
  "cIncome": string;
}
```

The unformatted geonames API returns an object, inside an array, inside an object:

```
Object { geonames: (1) […] }
 geonames: Array [ {…} ]
  0: Object { continent: "NA", capital: "Washington", languages: "en-US,es-US,haw,fr", … }
​​​  areaInSqKm: "9629091.0"
​​​​​  capital: "Washington"
​​​​​  continent: "NA"
​​​​​  continentName: "North America"
​​​​​  countryCode: "US"
​​​​​  countryName: "United States"
​​​​​  currencyCode: "USD"
​​​​​  east: -66.949185723
​​​​​  fipsCode: "US"
​​​​​  geonameId: 6252001
​​​​​  isoAlpha3: "USA"
​​​​​  isoNumeric: "840"
​​​​​  languages: "en-US,es-US,haw,fr"
​​​​​  north: 49.3844873
​​​​​  population: "327167434"
​​​​​  postalCodeFormat: "#####-####"
​​​​​  south: 24.543938895
​​​  west: -124.73259849600001
​​​
```

But with the mapping, I've turned it into an object, inside an array, inside and array. Not sure that's hepling me though.

```
Array [ (1) […] ]
 0: Array [ {…} ]
  0: Object { continent: "NA", capital: "Washington", languages: "en-US,es-US,haw,fr", … }
   areaInSqKm: "9629091.0"
   capital: "Washington"
   continent: "NA"
   continentName: "North America"
   countryCode: "US"
   countryName: "United States"
   currencyCode: "USD"
   east: -66.949185723
   fipsCode: "US"
   geonameId: 6252001
   isoAlpha3: "USA"
   isoNumeric: "840"
   languages: "en-US,es-US,haw,fr"
   north: 49.3844873
   population: "327167434"
   postalCodeFormat: "#####-####"
   south: 24.543938895
   west: -124.7325984960000
```

My last step is to bind the API response data to the view, but I can't access the data.

I suspect it's either because the API data isn't populating my interface properly, or becuase the object keys are nested a few levels in the response. But then again, I'm new to this so it might be something totally different. Thanks in advance and apologies for the data dump.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the API response is an object with the `geonames` field containing the `IWorld` objects but not an `IWorld` array.

In your `callApi` method, declare the received response as `any` type; and in the `map` operator, you should return the value from the `geonames` field.

```
callApi(url: string) {
  return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
    tap((data) => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError),
    map((responseData) => {
      console.log('Response data: ', responseData);

      return responseData.geonames;
    })
  );
}
```

Note that `countries` is any array, you can't directly display `countries` in HTML view.

Either if you want to display the first element of the `countries` you can do with `countries[0]./* field */` or work with the `*ngFor` directive to iterate and display each element in the array.

```
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Country Info</h1>
  <div class="country-info" style="margin-left: 10px">
    <p>
      Country Name: <span>{{ countries[0] && countries[0].countryName }}</span>
    </p>
    <p>Country Capital: <span>{{ countries[0] && countries[0].capital }}</span></p>
    <p>Country Region: <span></span></p>
    <p>Income Level: <span></span></p>
    <p>Population: <span>{{ countries[0] && countries[0].population }}</span></p>
    <p>Continent: <span>{{ countries[0] && countries[0].continentName }}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nlsjbh?file=src%2Fworld%2Fworld.service.ts)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! My IDE still highlights "responseData.geonames" in red, saying it's not recognized, but everything seems to work at runtime.

Comment: Otherwise, you should define an interface/class for the root response. `export interface CountryInfoResponse { geonames: IWorld[];  }`. And replace `any` from `this.http.get<any>(url)` to `this.http.get<CountryInfoResponse>(url)`